# Is this blue flowered, round leafed stinging nettle of the edible variety

Tags: identification

I'm aware that flowered/ing nettles should not be consumed but can anybody tell me if the nettles below are of the edible variety when younger?

I have searched extensively and only found references to nettles of the toothed leaf variety.

This specimen was found in the UK.

Thanks

[image: pic]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Green alkanet (Pentaglottis sempervirens) - for anyone wondering.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentaglottis_sempervirens

Comment: Great work on the ID, Carl! You should be able to Accept your own answer, which would help in cataloguing the question.

Comment: Thanks :) I can accept it tomorrow apparently owing to new account.

Comment: I think you actually answered the slightly older question that I originally referenced in my now-deleted answer (https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/51245/alkanet-or-forget-me-not). Not bad for someone new to the site :)  You may want to post an answer there, too.

Comment: OK thanks! .....